# How to make OFFSET and LIMIT attributes in postgresql query are optional when using SQLC to generate Golang code?

Tags: postgresql, go, orm, sqlc

Here is my query statement to be generated. But I want the offset and limit attributes are optional.

```
-- name: ListTransfersTo :many

SELECT *
FROM transfers
WHERE to_account_id = $1
ORDER BY created_at
OFFSET $2
LIMIT $3;
```

I try to do following https://github.com/sqlc-dev/sqlc/issues/1155 to solve this problem by using
`OFFSET sqlc.arg('offset', nullable => true)` and `LIMIT sqlc.arg('limit', nullable => true)` but it returns an error: expected 1 parameter to sqlc.arg; got 2 after using sqlc generate.
Thanks for your supports.

Comment: [`sqlc.narg`](https://docs.sqlc.dev/en/stable/howto/named_parameters.html#nullable-parameters) is used to indicate a nullable parameter (don't know if this works for `offset`/`limit` but [this](https://github.com/sqlc-dev/sqlc/issues/200#issuecomment-1653328385) may help).

Comment: It helped me to generate successfully but now the 
`
ListTransferToParams struct {
...
Limit sql.NullInt32,
}
`
I tried to pass 
`
ListTransferToParams{
...
Limit: 5,
}
`
into ListTransfersTo function to query for data, but at Limit key-val, it told me that `cannot use 5 (untyped int constant) as sql.NullInt32 value in struct literal`. How can I fix it?

Comment: You wanted a nullable parameter; that's represented as a `sql.Null*` so that is what you need to pass (the other option is a pointer). Note: Please don't put code in comments; edit the question (really hare to read in comments and insufficient space to properly describe the issue).